# How can I add an automated counter only when requirements are met

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a 'game' of sorts and I really want to make an event that when you have one or more workers, they will automatically 'click' the alien and add aliens to my counter. To make that a little more clear, I have an image of an alien and when I click it, I have a counter tick up by one. Then, I have a button that will hire workers and I want the automated counter to only work when I have 1 or more workers. I want the automated counter to add 1 alien to my aliens counter every second, increasing with every worker.

1 worker = 1 alien per second
2 workers = 2 aliens per second
etc.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Clicker!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3 id="head1"><span id="Aliens">0</span> aliens</h3>
    <h3 id="head2"><span id="Empires">0</span> empires</h3>
    <h3 id="head3"><span id="Spaceships">0</span> spaceships</h3>
    <h3 id="head4"><span id="Planets">0</span> planets</h3>
    <h3 id="head5"><span id="SolarSystems">0</span> solarsystems</h3>
    <h3 id="head6"><span id="Galaxies">0</span> galaxies</h3>
    <h3 id="head7"><span id="Workers">0</span> workers</h3>
    <!--<p>You need <span id="test">0</span> aliens to hire a worker!</p>--> <!--Need to make dynamic-->
    <img id="Alien" src="alien.png">
    <img id="whirl" src="galaxy.jpg" style="width:25em; height:25em;">
    <button id="Purchase">Hire Workers</button>
</body>
<script>    
$(function() {
$('#Alien').click(function() {
    incrementCounter();
});

function incrementCounter() {
    var previousCounter = parseInt($("#Aliens").text());
    previousCounter = isNaN(previousCounter) ? 0: ++previousCounter;

    $("#Aliens").text(previousCounter);

    if(previousCounter % 25 === 0) {
        $("#Empires").text(previousCounter/25);
    }

    if(previousCounter % 100 === 0) {
        $("#Spaceships").text(previousCounter/100);
    }

    if(previousCounter % 1000 === 0) {
        $("#Planets").text(previousCounter/1000);
    }

    if(previousCounter % 10000 === 0) {
        $("#SolarSystems").text(previousCounter/10000);
    }

    if(previousCounter % 100000 === 0) {
        $("#Galaxies").text(previousCounter/100000);
    }

}

function resetCounter() {
    $("#Aliens").text(0);
}
});

</script>   
<script id="s2">
$(function() {
$('#Purchase').click(function() {
    automaticCounter();
});

function automaticCounter() {
    var workers = parseInt($("#Workers").text());
    workers = isNaN(workers) ? 0: ++workers;

    $("#Workers").text(workers);

    var autoCounter = parseInt($("#Aliens").text());
    autoCounter = isNaN(autoCounter) ? 0: autoCounter - 10 * workers;

    $("#Aliens").text(autoCounter);
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

I have researched on some timers but they are literal timers to make a clock. I hope I am not too confusing!

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/bunwqw7x/)***

Essentially you are going to want to use a 1000 millisecond interval to check the text of the workers, and then iterate that amount of times by calling #Alien's click event.

```
var workerCheck = setInterval(function(){
  var workers = parseInt($("#Workers").text());
    if( workers > 0 ){
     for(var i = 0; i < workers; i++){
      $("#Alien").click();       
     }
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Completely forgot about loops

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `setInterval(function, interval)` on the window/global scope. See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers)